# Calling a class's method from Windows form application

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to call a method with the same name of its class (AHPModel) but accepts an integer argument, from a Windows form by creating an instance of the class, but it gives me an error of `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`, please could you help!

Thank you.

In the Form:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AHPModel model = new AHPModel(3, 3);
        model.AddCriteria(criteria);
        model.AddCriterionRatedChoices(0, night);
        model.AddCriterionRatedChoices(1, act);
        model.AddCriterionRatedChoices(2, cost);

        model.CalculateModel();

        GeneralMatrix calcCriteria = model.CalculatedCriteria;
        GeneralMatrix results = model.ModelResult;
        GeneralMatrix choices = model.CalculatedChoices;
    }

    catch (System.Exception excep)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
    }
}
```

My Class

```
public class AHPModel
{
    public AHPModel(int n)
    {

    }
    public void CalculateModel()
    {
        CalculatePriorities();
        CalculateChoices();
        CalculateFinalResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because your AHPModel class does not have a constructor to take 2 values as required by line `AHPModel model = new AHPModel(3, 3);`. 

Also, it has no function to `AddCriteria` and no `criteria` variable. 
Also, it has no function to `AddCriterionRatedChoices` and no varibles for `night, act and cost`.

Comment: @zizobiko25 Is the `AHPModel` class you posted is actual one. If yes, I wonder you should get a compile time error saying something like: `No Constructor that accepts two arguments...` but you posted `Null Reference Exception` which is a run time exception?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No, this is only part of code. I have got the required constructors and mentioned methods @SivaGopal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that I was passing null values of arrays that are locally declared to the method. But now I am able to access the targeted method from my windows form.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you have not created the parmeterized constructor for

`AHPModel model = new AHPModel(3, 3);`

You can do the `AHPModel model = new AHPModel(3, 3);` when you have class with constructor like below

```
public class AHPModel
 {
    public AHPModel(int n)
    {

    }
    public AHPModel(int n,int n)
    {

    }
    public void CalculateModel()
    {
        CalculatePriorities();
        CalculateChoices();
        CalculateFinalResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have those constructors in my code, but still getting the error notification when running the code @Upender

Comment: Thanks @Upender Singh, I just realised that I was passing null values of arrays that are locally declared to the method. But now I am able to access the targeted method from my windows form.